# How to format date using Locale with Jackson and Spring Boot

Tags: json, date, spring-boot, jackson, datetime-format

I have a Spring Boot Application which sends GET messages to the other serivce and gets JSON, in which one of his fields is like this: `2014-11-07T22:01:45Z`

How to format this date with requester `Locale`? The method I use is as below:

```
ResponseEntity<Repository> response = restTemplate.exchange(repoUrlBuilder(owner, repository_name), HttpMethod.GET, entity, Repository.class);
```

Repository date field is as below:

```
@JsonProperty(value="created_at")
Date createdAt;
```

Static defined format in `JsonProperty` annotation is not a solution.

Comment: Is there an opportunity to modify Jackson ObjectMapper to be based on request locale?